# on scroll function is only calling 1 function

Tags: javascript

am trying to add sticky tag to side Divs and am calling javascript for this, when am calling the function more than once in the same page only 1 div is affected and when i tried to make it 2 different functions for 2 different Divs is only calling the last function and skipping the other

```
<script>
    window.onscroll = function() {
      myFunctionR();
      myFunctionL();
    }

    var header = document.getElementById("stickDivL");
    var header = document.getElementById("stickDivR");
    var sticky = header.offsetTop;

    function myFunctionL() {
      var scrollDivL =  window.pageYOffset;  
      if (scrollDivL > sticky) {
        header.classList.add("sticky");
        header.classList.add("col-xl-3");
        header.classList.remove("col-xl-12");
      } else {
        header.classList.remove("sticky");
        header.classList.remove("col-xl-3");
        header.classList.add("col-xl-12");
      }
      
    };

    function myFunctionR() {
      var scrollDivR =  window.pageYOffset;  
      if (scrollDivR > sticky) {
        header.classList.add("sticky");
        header.classList.add("col-xl-3");
        header.classList.remove("col-xl-12");
      } else {
        header.classList.remove("sticky");
        header.classList.remove("col-xl-3");
        header.classList.add("col-xl-12");
      }
      
    };
</script>
```

Comment: You're using the `header` variable in both functions. There's a way to do this without all that duplicate code though: https://jsfiddle.net/Lq3km0je/

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning both values ​​to only 1 variable
try this

```
var header0 = document.getElementById("stickDivL");
var header1 = document.getElementById("stickDivR");
```

it happens because when you call `var header = document.getElementById("stickDivR");` you're overwriting the variable.

like

```
var Foo1 = 1
var Foo1 = 10
console.log(Foo1)
```

you'll see `10`

Comment: Did you solve your problem or do you still need help?